# db_insert a lot of records

Tags: 7, database, performance

I am struggling to sort out how to insert a lot of records using db_insert

Please see below for the code.

I can't have a for loop in the array. It breaks but I am dealing with looping through a lot of data. 48 (states) X 365 (# days) X 36 years.

What is the best way of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

```
$query = db_insert('HDD')
  ->fields(array(
  for ($s = 0; $s <= $cnt; $s++) {
    'HDDDAYS' => $time, //Loops through the dates
    'AL'=> $output1[$sts[0]][$dts[$s]],
    'AR'=> $output1[$sts[1]][$dts[$s]],
    'AZ'=> $output1[$sts[2]][$dts[$s]],
    'CA'=> $output1[$sts[3]][$dts[$s]],
    'CO'=> $output1[$sts[4]][$dts[$s]],
    'CT'=> $output1[$sts[5]][$dts[$s]],
    'DE'=> $output1[$sts[6]][$dts[$s]],
    'FL'=> $output1[$sts[7]][$dts[$s]],
    ....
    'WI'=> $output1[$sts[45]][$dts[$s]],
    'WV'=> $output1[$sts[46]][$dts[$s]],
    'WY'=> $output1[$sts[47]][$dts[$s]]
  }));
  $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your query fields first, then set your field values in a loop before executing the query.

Example (not tested):

```
$query = db_insert('HDD')->fields(array(
  'HDDDAYS',
  'AL',
  'AR',
  ...
));

for ($s = 0; $s <= $cnt; $s++) {
  $query->values(array(
    'HDDDAYS' => $time,
    'AL' => $output1[$sts[0]][$dts[$s]],
    'AR' => $output1[$sts[1]][$dts[$s]],
    ...
  ));
}

$query->execute();
```